# Error assigning scatter plot to specific bins

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, matplotlib

I am trying to `count` the number of `scatter points` in specific binned areas. The `code` works when I use a single `row` of `XY` data but when I try to `iterate` the same `script` over numerous `rows` a `TypeError` gets returned:

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Example:

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
X = np.random.randint(-80, 80, size=(100, 10))
Y = np.random.randint(0, 120, size=(100, 10))  

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

BIN_23_X = 0 
ang1 = -60, 60
ang2 = 60, 60
angle = math.degrees(math.acos(2/9.15))
E_xy = 0,60

Halfway = mpl.lines.Line2D((BIN_23_X,BIN_23_X), (0,125), color = 'white', lw = 1.5, alpha = 0.8, zorder = 1)
arc1 = mpl.patches.Arc(ang1, 70, 110, angle = 0, theta2 = angle, theta1 = 360-angle, color = 'white', lw = 2)
arc2 = mpl.patches.Arc(ang2, 70, 110, angle = 0, theta2 = 180+angle, theta1 = 180-angle, color = 'white', lw = 2)
Oval = mpl.patches.Ellipse(E_xy, 160, 130, lw = 3, edgecolor = 'black', color = 'white', alpha = 0.2)

ax.add_line(Halfway)
ax.add_patch(arc1)
ax.add_patch(arc2)
ax.add_patch(Oval)

ov1 = mpl.patches.Ellipse(ang1, 70, 110, alpha=0)
ov2 = mpl.patches.Ellipse(ang2, 70, 110, alpha=0)
ax.add_patch(ov1)
ax.add_patch(ov2)

for px, py in zip(X, Y):
    #Error occurs in the line below
    in_oval = Oval.contains_point(ax.transData.transform(([px, py])), 0)
    in_left = ov1.contains_point(ax.transData.transform(([px, py])), 0)
    in_right = ov2.contains_point(ax.transData.transform(([px, py])), 0)
    on_left = px < 0
    on_right = px > 0
    if in_oval:
        if in_left:
            n_bin = 1
        elif in_right:
            n_bin = 4
        elif on_left:
            n_bin = 2
        elif on_right:
            n_bin = 3
        else:
            n_bin = -1
    else:
        n_bin = -1

def bin_counts(xA, yA):
    bc = dict()
    E = Oval.contains_points(ax.transData.transform(np.array([xA, yA]).T), 0)
    E_l = ov1.contains_points(ax.transData.transform(np.array([xA, yA]).T), 0)
    E_r = ov2.contains_points(ax.transData.transform(np.array([xA, yA]).T), 0)
    L = np.array(xA) < 0
    R = np.array(xA) > 0
    bc[1] = np.sum(E & E_l)
    bc[2] = np.sum(E & L & ~E_l)
    bc[3] = np.sum(E & R & ~E_r)
    bc[4] = np.sum(E & E_r)
    return bc        

for xr, yr in zip(X, Y):
    print(bin_counts(xr, yr))
```

Error occurs in this line

```
in_oval = Oval.contains_point(ax.transData.transform(([px, py])), 0)
```

Traceback:

```
Studies/Datasets/codes/untitled4.py", line 73, in <module>
    in_oval = Oval.contains_point(ax.transData.transform(([px, py])), 0)

  File "/Users/jeremyalexander/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/patches.py", line 154, in contains_point
radius)

  File "/Users/jeremyalexander/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/path.py", line 493, in contains_point
return _path.point_in_path(point[0], point[1], radius, self, transform)

TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: Please consider simplifying your code so people can more easily understand it and help you.

Comment: @EdgarR.Mondragón, I've taken out some of the plotting code but the rest is essential to the problem.

Comment: Maybe try showing 2 blocks of code: "Code that works: ..." and "Code that doesn't work: ..."

Comment: One of the parameters that you are giving a function has more values that it can accept.  It expects a scalar or something it can convert to a scalar.  Review the requirements of the relevant function call, and review the type and shape of the inputs.

Comment: Doyou know what a traceback is?  Or how to tell us exactly where in your code the error is occuring?

Comment: @hpaulj, this has been added

Comment: Doesn't the stacktrace tell you whether problem occurs in `transform` or `contains_point`?  One guess is that `contains_point` expects one point, as opposed to 'points', and that the `transform` call produces multiple points.  And that the `px` and `py` values reference several points.

Answer (score 0):

I copy-n-pasted your code, and got this traceback - **the FULL traceback**, not just the last 2 lines!.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack52695533.py", line 35, in <module>
    in_oval = Oval.contains_point(ax.transData.transform(([px, py])), 0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/patches.py", line 154, in contains_point
    radius)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/path.py", line 493, in contains_point
    return _path.point_in_path(point[0], point[1], radius, self, transform)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

See the line in `patches.py` about `contains_point`?  Just going by the name I'm guessing it expects ONE point.  So now we need to test its inputs.

Adding

```
print(px, py)
print(ax.transData.transform(([px, py])))
```

right before the problem line, produces:

```
[ 22  12 -66  26  -9 -60  22  41  -6   7] [111  67   4 119  36  71 105 112  91  30]
[[ 10992.    4488. ]
 [-32656.    9662.4]
 [ -4384.  -22123.2]
 [ 10992.   15206.4]
 [ -2896.    2640. ]
 [ 55136.   24816. ]
 [  2064.   44035.2]
 [ 17936.   26294.4]
 [ 52160.   41448. ]
 [ 45216.   11140.8]]
```

As I suspected, you are trying to test for multiple points, not just one at a time.

`X` and `Y` are (100,10); you iterate on the first dimension, but still pass 10 values to `transform`.

Fortunately you provided a runnable example, otherwise I'd still be waiting for your response to my last comment.

Comment: Sorry hpaulj. As the code works with a single row of XY data, can it work with numerous rows or does it have to be rewritten?

Comment: A starting point would be to study the `contains_point` code, and see if it can adapted to work with multiple points at once.  I haven't done that, so can't help you.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for your help.